# Run Windows Application built in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows XP SP2

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have developed a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2010, i.e., using .Net Framework 4 and MS SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. I published the project and also configured to install prerequisites as:
1) Microsoft .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile
2) Windows installer 4
3) MS SQL Server 2008 Express

The application setup is then created!
I then try to run the setup on a Windows XP machine. The setup failed while installing SQL Server 2008 Express.

Please Help.

Comment: "The setup failed" doesn't provide much information. Can you be more specific about what "failed" means? What does the installer log say?

Comment: Do you want me to post the complete log details?

Comment: Um, no. Just the part that shows what failed. ;-) The rest would be pretty meaningless and just be a lot of noise.

Comment: Component SQL Server 2008 Express has failed to install with the following error message: "An error occurred attempting to install SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1."

I know its nothing much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, SQL 2008 Express (only database engine package) needs .NET 2 SP2 to be installed on Windows XP. did you include .NET 2 SP2 with your package?

Can you try to run SQL 2008 setup manually and post the error message that is shown to you?

Comment: I tried to run the setup manually.  It said after 5 minutes that SQL server 2008 express requires Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0 to be installed and a link to download. I am downloading it, will post again in a while.